# "OOP" in canvas correct way

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw something on canvas with sugar code that we received not that long time ago. I'm using babel of course. I have two questions. First of all you can find my code below:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

class Rectangle {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    };

    move() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
            if (event.keyCode === 37) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
                this.x--
                this.draw();
            }
            if (event.keyCode === 39) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
                this.x++
                this.draw();
            }
        })

    }
}


class Ball {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    };
}


const rect = new Rectangle(130, 50);
const ball = new Ball(60, 40)

setInterval(() => {
    rect.draw();
    rect.move();
    ball.draw();
}, 100);
```

I made two classes. One is rectangle, second ball. Rectangle is the one that can move with arrows. When i move, ball disapears for a brief second, then appears on the screen again. What am i doing wrong in this case? How game flow should look like properly?
Second question is: how can i make these two classes interract with each other? For example, i want that when rectangle will touch ball simple console.log will apear. Thanks

Comment: Look at your `move()` 's implementation and your invocation of `move()`

Comment: Move clearRect call inside interval function, before move and draw. I have reworked your example with some comments, hope this help: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld4mhu8s/1

Comment: from what i understand my console.log example should go in here
function update() {
    // game logic goes here
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       const thisItem = items[i];
       for (let j = i + 1; j < items.length; j++) {
           const otherItem = items[j];
           if (thisItem.intersects(otherItem)) {
              // do some stuff
             console.log('intersects')
           }
       }
    }
}

but nothing happens

Comment: Ouch you are adding a new event listener every 100ms... basics would be in main loop you do two things: update objects then draw them. For user interactions, they should update your objects out of the loop, but they should not call any drawing, your main loop should take care of it.

Comment: @KamilStaszewski, because code of itersects functions is missing. You need to implement it, before it will work. But this is hard effort. Suggestion is to use some existing libraries (there is a lot good 2D canvas engines). Other possible solution to use only bounding rectangles to detect intersections or hardcode only this intersections that you need

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Thought it's not that hard without any libraries...

Comment: Here's a good read when it comes time to implement collision detection. https://wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the code is yours. Since I prefer using `requestAnimationFrame` I'm adding an identifier for the request:  `let requestId = null;`.

The `move()` method of the rectangle deals only with the value of `x`, and takes the `key` as an attribute.

Also I've written the `frame` function that builds your animation frame by frame.

```js
function frame() {
  requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  rect.move(key);
  rect.draw();
  ball.draw();
}
```

On `keydown` you change the value for the `key` variable, you cancel the current animation, and you call the `frame` function to start a new animation.

I've added as well a `keyup` event to stop the animation on key up.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let key;
let requestId = null;

class Rectangle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fill();
    //ctx.closePath();
  }

  move(key) {
    if (key == 37) {
      this.x--;
    }
    if (key == 39) {
      this.x++;
    }
  }
}

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    //ctx.closePath();
  }
}

const rect = new Rectangle(130, 50);
const ball = new Ball(60, 40);

rect.draw();
ball.draw();

function frame() {
  requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  rect.move(key);
  rect.draw();
  ball.draw();
}


document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (requestId) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
  }
  key = event.keyCode;
  frame();
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  if (requestId) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
  }
});
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

PS: Please read this article [requestAnimationFrame for Smart Animating](https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)